# Alert inside a if-else test does not work - beginner

Tags: javascript

Edit : Sorry, i tried to narrow my issue with a simpler test and failed because it lacks the parenthesis. Original failing code I have :

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var element = document.getElementById('description');
        var correctTitle = document.getElementById('figureCaption');
        element.addEventListener('change', function() {
            if (element.value == picTitle) {
                alert("success! " + picTitle);
                /* var xmlHttp = null;
                xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlHttp.open("GET", "/WEB-INF/acceuil.jsp", false,
                        element.value);
                xmlHttp.send(); */

            } else  { alert("fail!  " + picTitle); }
        }, false);
    </script>
```

Comment: You are missing parentheses around the condition: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

Comment: if statement should be - `if(true)`

Comment: @NPE Please don't use w3schools.  http://www.w3fools.com/  Here is MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Comment: Have a look at the [MDN JavaScript tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Statements#if...else_Statement) and [learn how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging).

Comment: @Hogan I guess.. for this case it doesn't really matter even if OP refers w3schools

Comment: @exexzian - Did you read the site I linked?  It does matter if we all want (and we do) for it to stop being returned in search results.

Comment: I used parenthesis on the more complex test I had and no success so I have to modified my question. 

@Hogan why no w3schools?

Comment: @Poutrathor - Read this:  http://w3fools.com

Comment: @Hogan then you should refer to paul irish's update on w3fools as well - https://github.com/paulirish/w3fools/issues/50

Comment: @exexzian - I just read MDN and w3schools linked.  I believe MDN is much better... besides not having ads it includes links to other articles and topics which are relevant.

Comment: @Hogan I totally agree that MDN resources are far more credible and reliable but bashing a website again and again for its past mistake is not an solution.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for the tip. I found that the issue is "picTitle" is not defined. I will keep looking at it more and come back to you if I find nothing, do you mind ?

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/tcm44/

html

```
<input type="textbox" id="description"></textbox>
```

javascript

```
   var element = document.getElementById('description');
    var correctTitle = document.getElementById('figureCaption');
    element.addEventListener('change', function() {
        alert("plop");
    }, false);
```

Comment: I am really sorry, I had to update the question since there were 2 errors there. One was the lack of parenthesis, the second one I still don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that picTitle was not defined. Thus nothing happens. Thanks to @FelixKling for showing me the debug tool.

I then called my PicTitle variable using window to grab it even outside the java balise where i defined it. I hope it is okay.

```
alert("success! " + window.picTitle);
```